# Nginx port available for all url

Tags: nginx

I'm working with `Docker` and `Nginx` and this is my `default.conf` file :

```
server{
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
}

server{
        listen 80;
        server_name blog.domain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass   http://MY-IP:8080;
        }
}
```

So quick explanation :

- The defaut host serve my html folder, no problem for that.
- The url `blog.domain.com` serve a `Wordpress` application running on port 8080, no problem for that.

I have another application running on port 8081 (phpMyAdmin) and my problem is, if I try `http://MY-IP:8081` or `blog.domain.com:8081` it's ok, I can access PhpMyAdmin... Why ?

I don't want this port 8081 available for all url on my server.

Comment: Is your IP mapped to that url?

Answer (score 0):

PHPMyAdmin will work with only `proxy_pass` directive. You can deny the location to whole earth. I guess that Nginx is not the server listening on port 8080 as well as 80 but something else is listening on 8080 and you wish to have Nginx proxy to that server. In such case, this will work. This is minimum config :

```
# first server block    
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
        location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;                
                    }
        ## set phpmyadmin to a different path
        location /phpmyadmin {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8081/phpmyadmin;
        #allow 1.1.1.1;
        # deny all;
                            }
        } # end server
# second server block       
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name blog.domain.com;
        location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://i.p.v.4:8080;
                    }
        } # end server
```